# Recommend approach to dynamically setting object data in access

Tags: ms-access

When setting the data for a form  at run time I can either set

Me.RecordSource = some SQL

Or

Me.RecordSet = some recordset

The latter approach allows me to parameters to a saved query via querydefs, if I try the same for a report it says that it is no longer supported.

Is it possible to set the recordsource using a saved query with parameters to get around this or do I have to hard code the sql with where clauses to the recordsource?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: I have never used Recordset to set a form or report dataset. I also don't use parameterized queries. I use WHERE CONDITION argument of OpenForm and OpenReport. Exactly what are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need to change form or report dataset? Are you asking about a form or a report?

Comment: The Recordset method is for ADO, not DAO which you normally will use.